A question about faithful and full functors
Jiří Adámek in proposition 3.31 of his Abstract and Concrete Categories
The Joy of Cats says:
If F : A → B  is a full, faithful functor, then for every B-morphism f : F A → F A', there exists a unique A-morphism g : A → A' with F g = f.
I was wondering should not we presume that the functor F is bijective on objects in order to prove the theorem?
Fullness implies that there exists a morphism g : A → A' in Hom_A(A,A') with F g =f. And, faithfulness does imply that F cannot map two different morphism in Hom_A(A,A') to the same morphism in Hom_B(FA,FA') and hence this g should be unique in Hom_A(A,A'). However, unless otherwise we assume that it is bijective on objects, the functor F can map morphisms in other Hom sets (say Hom_A(X,Y) with X and Y objects of A) to this very f. So, necessarily, there is no unique morphism  in A for a given B-morphism f : F A → F A' if F is not bijective on objects. Of course, there is a unique morphism in Hom_A(A,A') to this given B-morphism (and basically in any other Hom set mapped to Hom_B(FA,FA') by the faithful and full functor F).
Maybe Jiří Adámek has already pointed this: when he says "there exists a unique A-morphism g : A → A' with F g = f", he means there is a unique g in  Hom_A(A,A') only or amongst all A-morphisms?
Thanks vey much.

Rephrasing slightly, the proposition says that the induced map $\mathrm{Hom}{\mathbf{A}}(A, A') \to \mathrm{Hom}{\mathbf{B}}(FA, FA')$ is bijective. What $f$ does on other hom-sets is irrelevant. In particular it does not need to be bijective on objects.

That $g$ is a morphism $A \to A'$ is part of the uniqueness specification. Formally, $\exists!(g : A \to A'). F_{A, A'}(g) = f$.

Thanks! now I see.
